# Can I connect my customer's workspaces to my Power BI Embedded capacity?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have Power BI Embedded capacity and currently use it to embed reports from my power bi service into a web based portal.

A customer has asked if I can connect to their workspaces from my tenant and embed their reports.

Is it possible to do this?   What would the customer need to do on their end to allow me to access the workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding can be made [with user credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core) (user name and password) from their tenant (usually used with embed for your organization, a.k.a. user owns data), or [with service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal) (application ID and secret) from their tenant (usually used with embed for your customers, a.k.a. app owns data). So they must give you their tenant ID (needed for the embedding). Then, depending on how you embed the Power BI elements, proper credentials.

Also, to make a note, that you can't assign their workspaces to your Power BI Embedded capacity, so probably they will need to get a dedicated capacity for their tenant too.